# SharePoint Rest API : Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to access a SharePoint Rest API, using authentication client_id + secret_id, and access_token.
Configuration has been made into SharePoint : generate client_id + secret_id ; allows read permissions on SharePoint Site for my App.
I can easily generate an access_token.
(tutorial https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/in-4-steps-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-tool/)

But when accessing SharePoint Rest API, I'm always facing the same error :

> Http response code: 401 Unauthorized
> Response: {"error_description":"Exception of type **'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}**

**1.** I try to request a simple:
*/_api/web?$select=Title*
Using this url:
*https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/Production/_api/web?$select=Title*

**2.** Another test is to request the content of a named folder (default "Shared Documents" library, in french "Documents Partagés"):
*/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{relative_url}')*
Using this url:
*https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/Production/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents Partagés')*

Maybe I don't use right pattern to join my SharePoint site, or to access to its library?

When I'm into my web navigator, I access to my SharePoint Sites using :
*https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/Production/Documents%20Partags/*

Into SharePoint, if I right click on the folder library, and get the link, I've get the following :
*https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/Production/Documents%20Partags*

On web, I've seen many example using another pattern with "sites" included into the URL.
For example : *https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/Production/_api/web?$select=Title*
If I use this syntax, I always obtain the error : "404 File not found".

So, which syntax is the good one?
Which pattern have I to used between "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/" and "/_api/web/" ?

- "/Production/" ?
- "/:f:/r/Production/" ?

How have I to write my {relative_url} ?

- Including site name (in these examples "/Production/Documents Partagés") ?
- Beginning with a "/"?
- Can I use special characters ("é") inside the URL
- SharePoint links seems to delete character "é" : have I to write URL with or without this character?
- Is http replacement ("%2", "%20") allowed? Or can I send a string with space characters and slash characters

Thank for help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's my first request on Stack Overflow.
Do you mean that my question was not published ?
It will be published when I will change my question, to make it more simple ?